# How to split HDFS file into multiple directories using some key on the data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a HDFS file with following sample data

> id name timestamp 
>  1 Lorem 2013-01-01 
>  2 Ipsum 2013-02-01 
>   3 Ipsum 2013-03-01

Now I want to split the data in multiple directory in format `/data/YYYY/MM/DD` such as record 1 goes to directory `/data/2016/01/01`.

There is MultiStorage UDF in pig which can be used split into single directory either by year or month or date. Is there any way by which I can split into multiple directory?

Answer (score 2):

you can choose from these three approach:

1. you can write shell script to do this task
2. you can write mapreduce job with partition-er class
3. you can create hive partitioned table and apply partition by year, month and day, but then dir name will have `partition column name=` as prefix in dir name:  `/data/year=2016/month=01/date=07`

Let me know which ever approach you prefer, I will update answer with an example based on that.

**update with shell-script solution:**

Given two input/source files with same content in hdfs:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/test_dir
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         79 2016-08-02 04:43 /user/cloudera/test_dir/test.file1
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera         79 2016-08-02 04:43 /user/cloudera/test_dir/test.file2
```

***Shell-script:***

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assuming src files are in hdfs, for local src file 
# processing change the path and command accordingly
# if you do NOT want to write header in each target file
# then you can comment the writing header part from below script

src_file_path='/user/cloudera/test_dir'
trg_file_path='/user/cloudera/trgt_dir'

src_files=`hadoop fs -ls ${src_file_path}|awk -F " " '{print $NF}'|grep -v items`

for src_file in $src_files
do
    echo processing ${src_file} file...

    while IFS= read -r line 
    do
       #ignore header from processing - that contains *id*
       if [[ $line != *"id"* ]];then

        DATE=`echo $line|awk -F " " '{print $NF}'`
        YEAR=`echo $DATE|awk -F "-" '{print $1}'`
        MONTH=`echo $DATE|awk -F "-" '{print $2}'`
        DAY=`echo $DATE|awk -F "-" '{print $3}'`
                file_name="file_${DATE}"

        hadoop fs -test -d ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY

        if [ $? != 0 ];then
            echo "dir not exist creating... ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY "
            hadoop fs -mkdir -p ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY
        fi


        hadoop fs -test -f ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$file_name

                if [ $? != 0 ];then
                     echo "file not exist: creating header... ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$file_name"
                     echo "id name timestamp" |hadoop fs -appendToFile - ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$file_name
                fi

        echo "writing line: \'$line\' to file: ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$file_name"
        echo $line |hadoop fs -appendToFile - ${trg_file_path}/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/$file_name
       fi
    done < <(hadoop fs -cat $src_file)
done
```

`manageFiles.sh` script ran as:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ./manageFiles.sh
processing /user/cloudera/test_dir/test.file1 file...
dir not exist creating... /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/01/01 
file not exist: creating header... /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/01/01/file_2013-01-01
writing line: '1 Lorem 2013-01-01'  to file: /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/01/01/file_2013-01-01
dir not exist creating... /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/02/01 
file not exist: creating header... /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/02/01/file_2013-02-01
writing line: '2 Ipsum 2013-02-01'  to file: /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/02/01/file_2013-02-01
dir not exist creating... /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/03/01 
file not exist: creating header... /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/03/01/file_2013-03-01
writing line: '3 Ipsum 2013-03-01'  to file: /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/03/01/file_2013-03-01
processing /user/cloudera/test_dir/test.file2 file...
writing line: '1 Lorem 2013-01-01'  to file: /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/01/01/file_2013-01-01
writing line: '2 Ipsum 2013-02-01'  to file: /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/02/01/file_2013-02-01
writing line: '3 Ipsum 2013-03-01'  to file: /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/03/01/file_2013-03-01

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/trgt_dir/2013/03/01/file_2013-03-01
id name timestamp
3 Ipsum 2013-03-01
3 Ipsum 2013-03-01
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks. Hive file format looks fine only issue using hive partitioned table is it will store the file in ORC file format, I want to use text format. Can you also tell me what is the shell script that will do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a **hive partitioned table** on the timestamp column and by using **HCatStorer** store the data in pig only.

This way you may not get directory of your choice but you can get the data in multiple directory as you asked.